# Re-phrasing: how to check if all elements from one ArrayList are in order or as same order as previous ArrayList in another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

ArrayList one contains

```
['a', 'b', 'm',  'd']
```

ArrayList two contains

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'b', 'u',  'm',  'd'].
```

If two.containsAll(one) returns true,

How to check if all the elements of one are in order in two?
Another words:
How to check if Position order is [a < b < m < d ] in two, as they are in this position in one.

Comment: Do you want to check the order or it's ranking?

Comment: Order. they don't need to be in same position, but in same order. Thanks

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Nope it doesn't, It boiled down to **Is my list1 a subset of list2 and the order(not position) of the elements are same**

Comment: Please provide a code example so we are able to better assist.

Comment: I did the following as John Bollinger suggested: two.retainAll(one); comparing if one and two are equals. Thanks to All for the efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following procedure:

1. Make modifiable copies of `ArrayList`s one and two to use as work space (i.e. `work1` and `work2`).
2. Remove all elements of `work2` that do not appear in `work1` (consider method `retainAll()`).  These contribute nothing to the analysis.
3. Iterate over the remaining elements in the `work2`, and replace any consecutive runs of the same element with a single instance of that element.  (I suppose here that list one does not contain any dupes; if it may do then also perform dupe removal on `work1`.)
4. Remove from `work1` any elements that do not appear in `work2`.  These are irrelevant to the question of `work2`'s order.
5. Compare the two work lists for equality (`equals()`).

This handles all cases, including those where list two contains duplicate elements and / or does not contain all the elements of list one (and even where one or both lists are empty).

---

**Alternatively,** you can do it without copying or modifying the lists via this procedure:

Iterate over list one, and for each element `e1`

1. find the last appearance of `e1`, if any, in list two (`lastIndexOf()`).  If it appears, then
2. scan the preceding elements of list two for each element following `e1` in list one (consider forming a `subList()` of list two and using its `contains()` method).  This assumes no dupes in list one.

List two is consistent with the order defined by list one if and only if none of the scans performed in step 2 fund any elements.

---

Either way, the actual code for your homework is left to you to write.

Comment: Suggestion one worked. RetainAll() method didn't come in my head... That was more than enough! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no duplicates in the `second`, and `second` contains all the elements in `first`, you can use `List.indexOf` to compare adjacent elements in `first`:

```
static <T> boolean ordered(List<? extends T> first, List<? extends T> second) {
  if (!first.isEmpty()) {
    int prev = second.indexOf(first.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < first.size(); ++i) {
      if (prev > (prev = second.indexOf(first.get(i)))) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Example invocations:

```
System.out.println(ordered(
    Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'm', 'd'),
    Arrays.asList('c', 'a', 't', 'b', 'u', 'm', 'd'))); // Prints true.
System.out.println(ordered(
    Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'd', 'm'),
    Arrays.asList('c', 'a', 't', 'b', 'u', 'm', 'd'))); // Prints false.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used the [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm concept and applied it to lists.

```
public boolean containsAll(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2)
{
  if(list1.size() == 0 || list2.size() < 0)
   return false;
  int k = 0;
  int list1Size = list1.size();
  int x = list1.get(k);
  for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(); ++i)
  {
    if(list2.get(i) == x)//if an element matches then goto the next element in list2
    {
     k++;
     if(k == list1Size)
       return true;
     x = list1.get(k);//get next element of list1 to match with
    }
    }
 return false;
}
```